# Is there, a better method to remove duplicates values from a list when using a dictionary instead of set(), to preserve the values insertion order?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

When using `set()` to remove duplicates values from a list the values order of insertion is not preserve:

```
mylist = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'c']

results = list(set(mylist))

print(results)

# output
>>> ['a', 'd', 'b', 'c']
```

To preserve the values insertion order when removing duplicated values from a list, I found away around `set()` by using a `dictionary` as fallow:

```
mylist = ['b', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'c']

results = list({value:"" for value in mylist})

print(results)
>>> ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c']
```

Does a better method exist, than one that I used above, to duplicates values from a list when using a dictionary instead of set(), to preserve the the values insertion order?

Comment: `list(dict.from_keys(mylist))`

Comment: @DaniMesejo: `dict.fromkeys`, not `dictionary.from_keys`, but close.

Comment: @Alex: Yeah, your solution is a good one, and it's what `dict.fromkeys` does more efficiently than a hand-rolled `dict` comprehension (it sets all the values to `None` by default, not the empty string, but given you don't use the values, it hardly matters) by doing the work entirely at the C layer, where a `dict` comprehension still involves the bytecode interpreter (even if it does use specialized, optimized bytecodes to run faster than building a `dict` with regular loops and assignment). For longish inputs, `dict.fromkeys` shaves the runtime by about a quarter (and it's shorter to type).